# Hibernate @OneToMany don't remove child from list when updating parent

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have create mapping between Paper and Mcq question as below.

```
    public class Paper {
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade =      {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
     @JoinTable(name = "paper_mcq",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "paper_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "mcq_id")})
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Mcq> mcqs = new HashSet<>();
```

}

When I'm updating Paper entity it's deletes all MCQ.

SQL Output:

```
Hibernate: delete from paper_mcq where paper_id=?
```

Comment: How are you updating the parent can you please provide some demo code.

Comment: I'm using simple save mathod override fun savePaper(paper: Paper): Paper {
        // Create and save instantly into database
        return paperRepo.save(paper)
    }

Answer (score 1):

I believe your paper object in paperRepo.save(paper) don't have mcqs at this time, and the cascading sees that as a deletion. I'm just assuming that you're receiving your object from json and the @JsonIgnore simply ignores the deserialization.

So there are multiple options to solve that:
- Query the mcqs and set them before updating
- remove @JsonIgnore and add those in your json
- remove the cascading and set it manually

Comment: Thanks @Marc, I query all the mcqs and then updated with paper details. Now its working like charm.